# Add api from Meteor to develop in Eclipse or Aptana

Tags: eclipse, node.js, meteor, aptana

I have searched on meteor docs (http://docs.meteor.com/) to find a way to add api in Eclipse or Aptana and develop my applications inside this IDE.

I Know how to add external libraries in my project but i don't know what are the library to add for use Meteor inside Eclipse / Aptana and use (for example) autocomplete feature so i can type:

> **Meteor.** <-- And I want that eclipse show all functions

there is any sort of list of library to add? can you help me?

thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here is !! ;)  https://github.com/angelozerr/tern.java/wiki/Tern-&-Meteor-support

I used it at Eclipse and with sublime text, and it is very usefull